# Retornar todos os resultados utilizando preg_match

Tags: php, regex

Estou precisando retornar alguns resultados da busca "ex: Agência Digital" da primeira página do Google utilizando preg_match + RegEx, porém não está retornando todos os 10 valores no array, apenas o primeiro. Como resolvo?

Ex:

```
$document = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com.br/search?q=Ag%C3%AAncia+Digital');

preg_match_all('/<li class=\"g\">([^`]*?)<\/li>/', $document, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Comment: Testei aqui o seu código, veio um  array com duas chaves e 10 elementos(html) em cada porém tive que utilizar a opção exibir código fonte do navegador.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando se analisa sintaticamente o HTML de uma página com Expressões Regulares, infelizmente ser específico pode ser um problema.

Nesses casos você deve capturar tudo aquilo que está dentro de um delimitador de conteúdo específico, no seu caso os `<li></li>`. E por causa da `?` no seu grupo você desfaz a gulodice do quantificador `*`.

Ao pé da letra é como se você estivesse dizendo: *Qualquer coisa que não seja um backtick, em qualquer quantidade, mas se não tiver nenhum, tudo bem também*.

Tanto é que bastou remover a interrogação e todos os outros resultados apareceram.